# Getting Auto Deploy to work with MSBuild on a build server

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

Please pardon a newbie's question about MS TFS and Visual Studio 2012, I hope I'm using the correct vocabulary.

Our shop has recently moved to MS TFS and Visual Studio 2012 to build internal web services for integration.  Currently we have a TFS 2010 Server running on Server2008R2 and a Build server on a Windows 7 box, our dev application server is also running Server2008R2.  I have been given the job of getting a nightly build and deployment running.  I have the build definition working but the deployment portion is not functioning.  I have installed Web Deploy on both the dev application server and the build server as per these articles:

http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/how-to-auto-deploy-web-application-with-tfs-build-server.html

and

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy

We have configured an user, web_deploy_dev in active director and that user is a local admin on the dev app server.

The parameters added to the build definition are:
    /p:DeployOnBuild=True

```
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish 

/p:MSDeployServiceURL="https://PA-APPSRV1-DEV:8172/msdeploy.axd"  /* double quotes not in original code */ 

/p:DeployIISAppPath="DW/DWServices"   /* E:\Webroot\DW\DWServices */

/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True 

/p:MsDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC 

/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 

/p:UserName=migp\web_deploy_dev 

/p:Password=******
```

I suspect that MSBUILD is not even calling msdeploy.exe as I see no errors in the windows event and application logs, but I do not know all the places to look.  I can use a web browser and connect to the service on the dev app server as the web_deploy_dev user from the build server, I receive a web page not found error after inputting user name and PW, but I assume that is to be expected.

I am at a loss as to where to look next, I've tried searching the web but nothing I try seems to work.

Thank you in advance for your help and input.

Roy

Comment: Can you specify what is the error you are seeing along with the stack trace. on the server side, go to event viewer and under "Application And Services Logs" you should see "Microsoft Web Deploy". See if you see any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are experiencing a problem where your build completes and claims success, but you aren't getting any error and nothing is actually deployed. When I've experienced this with my TeamCity build server, the problem was that MSBuild was not set up on the machine that would do the building and deploying. These are my steps to resolve the problem I think you might be having:

1. Make sure that at least Visual Studio Express is installed. you can tell if a full enough version of Visual Studio is installed by navigating to the
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\` directory. If you see folders like `10.0`, `11.0`, or '12.0', look inside them and verify that there is a `Microsoft.WebApplications.targets` file. Note the versions that pass that check.
2. In your Build Configuration, add a `/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0` or whatever version of Visual Studio is appropriate.

Let me know if this gets you anywhere or not. I'm really curious to hear if you are finding any errors or logs anywhere. Basically, in my experience using Web Deploy and MSBuild with TeamCity, if the machine that is building and deploying doesn't have the MSBuild installed with the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file, it silently fails.